# minimizing std. dev. in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm new to Linear Programming and trying to create an automated scheduling algorithm, and am having trouble defining the *objective function and decision variables*. Any help would be appreciated:

Let there be E employees who need to be assigned to K types of shifts distributed over N days. Each shift K has an associated dissatisfaction score D that is constant among each employee. The goal of the problem is to assign each employee such that the standard deviation in their total dissatisfaction scores are minimized (that is, to create an "equitable" assignment).

Comment: This could be of some help if you can use ILP: https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/12/19/ilp-part-18/

Also, for stdev you need to multiply variables which will make it slow but is technically doable.

Comment: What if you were asked to simply minimize the range of the scores (max minus min) instead of stdev?  Might be a lot easier to solve and effectively good enough?

Comment: square-root is a monotonically increasing function, so one can minimize the sum-square error in place of the RMS error.  Now the problem falls into the category of "optimization of a quadratic objective function with linear constraints" which is very well understood with great tools for solving.